# Multiple (3) contextual drawers in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I'm looking for a way to have multiple contextual drawers in Flutter. So far I've been able to have two drawers - one on the left, and one on the right. However, what I really want to accomplish is to have multiple contextual drawer menu via the action buttons on the top right.

With the limitation of two drawers by default, I tried to "swap" the endDrawer programatically. I wasn't able to accomplish this because the drawer widget is "final". So, then the next set of solution is to perhaps rebuild the internal structure of the drawer. But I don't know how to do this as I'm still new to flutter.

So my question is:

1. Is there an elegant way to have multiple drawers? or,
2. Given a widget, how do I rebuild its internal?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: [
          // Menu 1
          Builder(builder: (context) => IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.filter_alt),onPressed: () {
            ScaffoldState scaffoldState = Scaffold.of(context);

            // I'm trying to rebuild the drawer here
            //scaffoldState.widget.drawer.build...

            scaffoldState.openEndDrawer();
          },),),
          // Menu 2
          Builder(builder: (context) => IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.filter_alt),onPressed: () {
            ScaffoldState scaffoldState = Scaffold.of(context);

            // I'm trying to rebuild the drawer here
            //scaffoldState.widget.drawer.build...

            scaffoldState.openEndDrawer();
          },),),
          // Menu 3
          Builder(builder: (context) => IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.filter_alt),onPressed: () {
            ScaffoldState scaffoldState = Scaffold.of(context);

            // I'm trying to rebuild the drawer here
            //scaffoldState.widget.drawer.build...

            scaffoldState.openEndDrawer();
          },),),
        ]
        //actions: [Icon(Icons.notifications)],
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                child: Text('Drawer Header'),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),

              ListTile(
                title: Text('Left Menu Item 1'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),

              ListTile(
                title: Text('Left Menu Item 2'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      endDrawer: Drawer(
        child: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                child: Text('Drawer Header 2'),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),

              ListTile(
                title: Text('Right Menu Item 1'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  // Update the state of the app.
                  // ...
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Right Menu Item 2'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  // Update the state of the app.
                  // ...
                },
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Understanding flutter a bit more and just thinking to myself. I suppose the state of the drawer's parent will need to change in order to rebuild the drawer itself. I think if I create multiple drawers and store them in a list, then resetting the parent's state should allow me to tell it which drawer to use. I will try this when I get back in front of my pc. I just don't want to lose this thought. Wish me luck.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty new to flutter but I faced the same problem. Couldn't find a way to make 3 drawers but found an alternative that might or might not be what you want.

`showModalBottomSheet` opens up a sheet (a lot like a drawer) from the bottom and you can add as many of these as you like. You can view the documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html).

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that I'm using for 2 drawers (although could be adjusted to work with more, either with multiple bools or an enum...):

Defined a bool `_openDrawer1 = true;`

I created 2 drawer widgets, `Widget drawer1` and `Widget drawer2`.

I gave `drawer:`  a ternary operator:

```
drawer: _openDrawer1
          ? drawer2()
          : drawer1(),
```

I then have a function to open either drawer that takes a bool as an argument and references a `key:` in the scaffold:

```
  void _openDrawer(bool drawerType) {
    setState(() {
      _openDrawer1 = drawerType;
    });
    _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
  }
```

And then 2 buttons with:

`onTap () {_openDrawer(true)}`

and

`onTap () {_openDrawer(false)}`